# Ruby: slicing out n elements from an array centered around some index

Tags: ruby

Here's an array, an index, and a number n representing how many items I want to slice out

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
index = 5
n = 3
```

The above arguments translates to `give me 3 elements centered around index 5`, which would be `[4,5,6]`

If the number is even, then just make an arbitrary choice of having the extra element on the left or right side. Eg: Given `n = 2`, `[4, 5]` and `[5,6]` are both equally valid.

But then we have to consider boundary cases. Supposing `index = 1` and `n = 5`, it should return `[0,1,2,3,4]`, because we've hit the boundary on the left side.

Similarly, Supposing `index = 8` and `n = 5`, it should return `[5,6,7,8,9]` since we hit the boundary on the right side.

What's a nice way to write this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a slice by using [`Array#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D)

Therefore, something like the following should work fine:

```
arr[offset - (count / 2), count]
```

Provided offset and count are Fixnums, ruby will handle the division and rounding correctly to meet the requirements you gave.

EDIT | You should probably sanitize the arithmetic too, since negative offsets have a special meaning to `#slice`.  Then you also want to sanitize the end value to allow the entire count to fit:

```
arr[
  [[offset - (count / 2), 0].max, arr.size - count].min,
  count
]
```

Getting a bit hairy now, but that's it anyway.

Comment: Oh, I was trying to calculate the left and right bounds, not where the left (or right) bound should begin. I get it now.

Comment: Yeah, you always want to use an offset/count operation, rather than a range operation. Then the only issue you need to solve is determining what the best margin left of the "center" is.